# How to visualize more than one kernel per layer in histograms using tensorboard

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I am currently using Tensorflow 2.0 with a simple CNN, i am initializing the first layer with some handcrafted filters that i would like to visualize during the learning process.

In the histogram part of tensorboard i only see the first kernel of the layer but i would like to see all of them. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Creating a small function that does this on the displaycallback during the epoch end is the way i solved it, is not the cleanest , and would be nice if someone can correct it :)

```
class DisplayCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    variables_names = [v.name for v in model.trainable_variables]

    with file_writer_cm.as_default():
        for i in range(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape[3]):
            tf.summary.histogram(variables_names[0].split('/')[0]+"/kernel_"+str(i), model.layers[0].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,i], step=epoch)
```